# Power loss in Nissan Primera SVE. Possible causes?

Tags: nissan, noise, performance, primera

I have a Nissan Primera SVE (2002 model). Mileage is about 200000KM. Had its timing chain replaced at the end of 2013 because it was "stretched". Since then, I haven't had any problems (up until now).

Yesterday evening, I noticed that the car was struggling to pick up speed, as if the engine wasn't getting enough power. There is a small but noticeable whirring noise coming from the engine.

[Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLOkDy8FQw0&feature=youtu.be) to a Youtube video that I recorded a few minutes ago. Maybe I'm just hearing things?

***Update 1***: This morning, it seemed as though the engine took longer than usual to start.

***Update 2***: At higher speeds, the car tends to shake.

Comment: While it was a good thought to include the video, I'm not sure it's of any help at all ... I personally am not hearing anything out of the ordinary, but smartphone video usually doesn't do well in the sound department, so who knows. Really, there isn't enough information given here to provide you with any kind of an answer.

Comment: @Paulster2 To be honest, I'm probably imagining it because of the power loss.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about what could be going on with the power loss? Include the exact year/make/model/engine/mileage, what maintenance has been done recently (or lifetime), and anything else which may be pertinent, like if you've changed gas stations. There isn't much of a question here.

Comment: @DucatiKiller This morning, it seemed as though the car took longer to start up. When at slow speeds, the car can jump a bit, as though it is about to stall.